# How to get uwp package logo with c# and wpf

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I wanna make a classic start menu program in Windows.

And I write it with C# and WPF in visual studio 2022.

Using windows SDK in C#, PackageManager Class.

I can't load logos from UWP application.

I use 'package.logo' this url type member.

```
//get all package in system
string sid = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString();
PackageManager pm = new PackageManager();
List<Package> listPackage = new List<Package>(pm.FindPackagesForUserWithPackageTypes(sid, PackageTypes.Main).ToArray());

//remove non UWP package there
listPackage.RemoveAll(A => A.Logo == null);
listPackage.RemoveAll(A => A.GetAppListEntries().Count == 0);

//get single package information
foreach(Package p in listPackage)
{
            var u = p.logo; 
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(u);
            ...
}
```

It runs but throw a exception shows that the path doesn't exist.

And I try

```
package.entrylist.displayinfo.GetLogo();
```

There's some samples show that parameter should be new Size(1,1).

It looks like

```
var rstream = entry.displayinfo.GetLogo(new Size(1,1));
```

It failed.
Whatever the size I put in, It still throw a exception that can't load the logo;
It failed too.

Is there any authority problem or there would be other good way to get the UWP information.

By the way, I run the generated program directly and run as Administrator, the program close immediately.

Comment: Do you develop packaged Wpf app?

Comment: not a app. It is more like a Wpf style desktop program.

Comment: Not all the logo are avaiable, please use try-catch block to access.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna make a classic start menu program in Windows. And I write it with C# and WPF in visual studio 2022. Using windows SDK in C#, PackageManager Class.

You can't get package info with Unpackaged WPF project, the Package  class only avaiable for package project, please make  Windows Application Packaging Project and add your wpf as reference project and then it will be effect. for more please refer to [Set up your desktop application for MSIX packaging in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)

```
PackageManager manager = new PackageManager();
 var packages = manager.FindPackagesForUser(string.Empty);
 foreach (var package in packages)
 {
    
     var appEntries = await package.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
     var firstApp = appEntries.FirstOrDefault();
     if (firstApp != null)
     {
         try
         {
             var res = firstApp.DisplayInfo.GetLogo(new Size(10, 10));

             BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
             bitmap.SetSource(await res.OpenReadAsync());
             image_list.Add(bitmap);
            
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {


         }

     }

 }
```

Comment: I use this class to get other UWP application's information, not my project information.

Comment: You  need enable packageQuery capability

Comment: I use this way after , it failed too. It seems some authority problem.

Comment: I will try the packageQuery capability.

Comment: If we don't add the capability, it will throw access denied exception

Comment: I think the await word is the key to solute in a problem.

Comment: can you explain it ?

Comment: Yeah, as you say, it always throws the exception. But I also can't find the way to add capability in.

Comment: I have to say packageQuery  only avaiable uwp project or packaged project.

Comment: Because I didn't use await word when I call GetAppListEntriesAsync(). I think maybe I call GetLogo before the GetAppListEntriesAsync() called completly. So it get some Synchronize problem.

Comment: So, do you mean you have get the logo bitmap successfully with await  call  right ?

Comment: Not yet, I'm changing the struct of my code. I can't compile it.

Comment: Please let me know what problem you are viewing.

Comment: Yep,  sorry guys, but we have policy. you can open chatroom for this case

Comment: my reputation is not enough to open chatroom , I will try and make you know.

Comment: I'm busy recently, sorry.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:“找不到元素。 (0x80070490)”

Comment: You may need call the method in the try-catch block.